# vba: copy sheet with named destination

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a copy of a sheet with data. 
I managed to create a copy with this code, but want to create it with a defined name

```
Dim outsheet As String
outsheet = "SAP Import"

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(outsheet)
wsCopy.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(outsheet)
```

Now I would like to change the name. The obvious solution is however not implemented in VBA (Parameter unknown)

```
Dim strSheetTemp As String
strSheetTemp = outsheet + "-temp"
wsCopy.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSheetTemp)
```

How can I create a named copy?
Or how can I get the name of the copy to rename it ?

Comment: Use '&', not '+' adding strings

Comment: That is not the main problem. It does not compile because Destination is not known as an argument.

Comment: Destination is not known, because sheet with name 'strSheetTemp' does not exist yet, look at @horst answer, that should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the sheet can only be named (or renamed in this case) after being copied.

```
Dim outsheet As String
outsheet = "SAP Import"
Sheets(outsheet).Copy After:=Sheets(outsheet)
Sheets(Sheets(outsheet).Index + 1).Name = outsheet & "-temp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Dim outsheet As String
outsheet = "SAP Import"

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Set wsCopy = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(outsheet)

wsCopy.Copy After:=wsCopy
ActiveSheet.Name = outsheet & "-temp"
```

Following your trial philosophy...

In order to change the name you should use the property .Name.
That one will work in your case.

Hope it helps

Comment: Shorter code by reference to set sheet variable `wsCopy` (and avoiding possible confusion between `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook`) :-; `wsCopy.Copy After:=wsCopy`

Comment: Noted. I was just trying to keep the same philosophy.